# How to Model a TimeField in Django?

Tags: django

I have modeled a class called ConversationHistory. Whenever an instance is created I wish to set the current date and current time.

```
class ConversationHistory(models.Model):
    contact_date        = models.DateField(_(u"Conversation Date"),      blank=True)
    contact_time        = models.DateTimeField(_(u"Conversation Time"),  blank=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConversationHistory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.contact_date    = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.contact_time    = datetime.datetime.now()
```

The idea is that the user can later still adjust the date and time as two different fields.

I am now a bit lost how to make the time field only to show and accept time, rather than date and time. I recon it is not possible to have a time field without datetime, but then how would I show only the time in the form?

Comment: There is a [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Comment: in your form you should be able to format the field like [contact_time.strftime("%H:%M")](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: @César yes that would do it. :) Just one last thing, in order to remove the seconds, I need to do it in the form widget declaration?

Comment: Model, sorry if I misunderstood your question

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood you. It works in Model thanks :) You both should put this as an answer, so I can give you some karma ;)  I used both your solutions.

Comment: @Kave do you want to remove the seconds or just set to 0 seconds?

Comment: Removing would be great. :) 20:35 only - I have done it like this: `self.contact_time    = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")` but I am open to better ways

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want only time, [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) is what you need:

```
class ConversationHistory(models.Model):
    contact_date = models.DateField(_(u"Conversation Date"), blank=True)
    contact_time = models.TimeField(_(u"Conversation Time"), blank=True)
```

You can take advantage of the `auto_now_add` option:

> class TimeField([auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options])
>
> A time, represented in Python by a datetime.time instance. Accepts the
>   same auto-population options as DateField.

If you use the `auto_now_add`, it will automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.

```
class ConversationHistory(models.Model):
    contact_date = models.DateField(_(u"Conversation Date"), auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    contact_time = models.TimeField(_(u"Conversation Time"), auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thats very neat with auto_now_add. That means I don't even need to do it manually in the ctor anymore? nice

Comment: I thing you should be using default=datetime.datetime.now instead of auto_now_add, the problema being that you can't override auto_now_add

Comment: I just realized I can't even have the setting within the model's constructor. Since even editing the items always shows the current date and time.  I need to set this within the view upon creating a new instance only.